# how to get the dynamically generated IDs of Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm trying to get the dynamically generated ID's of my modals. So this is what my code looks like:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM currentstatus";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
     while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
         echo '<div class="modal fade" id="'.$r['rackName'].'" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'.$r['rackName'].'</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>';
     }
  ?>
```

.$['rackName'] is my dynamic ID

I call this modal, using the following code:

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$r['rackName'].'">'.$r['rackName'].'</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the show event and get the ID like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      console.log( $(this).prop('id') );
    });
});
```

Comment: I need the ID on load. Is it possible?

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver! Thanks a ton! :)